# "Res.redirect" Not Working when making Ajax call from React to Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

On the client Side i make an ajax call to the node

```
const res = await axios.post('/api/stripe', toPost);
```

where 'toPost' is an object with a bunch of key value pairs which I need on the backend.

After doing a few bits on the backend I then want to redirect the user to the 'thank you' page. So I thought i could end the response with something as simple as

```
res.redirect('/thankyou');
```

Although this shows up in the network tab on developer tools with status code 200. Nothing happens.

Would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: I think you won't be able to follow the redirect from within an ajax request, try setting some kind of flag in your response and do a window.location.href if the flag is set on the client side.

Comment: I agree with Akhil that you can't do a server-redirect in the middle of an ajax request. If you are using React (as your title suggests), you shouldn't be doing server-side redirects anyway. That disrupts the flow of your application unnecessarily. I suggest you use React Router in your application and then render <Redirect> component when done: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to redirect React client javascript with server redirects.

Try this on client:

```
axios.post('/api/stripe', toPost)
.then( (response) => {
  if (response.ok && window){ 
    window.location.href="/thankyou"; 
    // or <Redrect to="/thankyou" /> if you are using react-router
  }
})
```

Comment: superb, man. thanks a lot. all working. ended up going with res.redirect.

Comment: Where do you put the `<Redirect />` since you can't put an expression in there, it's supposed to be a function call or an assignment?

Comment: `<Redirect />` should be rendered inside another component ( refer to [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) ). The example above is a callback triggered after REST response; depending on your set up the answer where to place `<Redirect />` might be different. Inside `then` you can use `history.push`

Answer (score 0):

The thing you can do is in the ajax call answer `setRedirect(true)` and next in the render put a
`{redirect &&  <Redirect to='/thankyou ' />}`
or as Max Gram told you use `history.push('/thankyou')`