# Middleware to Check if a User is Authenticated in Node.js redirect

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

After success login, I give to user 60 min session of Authenticated in `Node express server`. If user in my `react app` want to get list of childrens, I have to check Authenticated and here I have problem, I do axios request `get` and in my file `app.js(node)` I do :

```
app.get('/childrenList', isUserLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){
    children.getChildrenList(req, res, next);
    });
```

and my function isUserLoggedIn

```
function isUserLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user_id || typeof(req.session.user_id)==='undefined') {      
        res.redirect('/login');            
        }
    else{
        next();
        }
    }
```

My redux/actions function

```
export function childrenList(objSql,type){
    return {
        type: type,
        payload: new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            axios.get('/childrenList', objSql,{
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                resolve(response);
                });
            })
        }
    }
```

Eveythign work fine if user refresh page (redirect to `'/login'`) but if user just click button "Get childrens" after session expired node dosen't redirect to page `'/login'`. How I can redirect after `session expired`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Res.redirect" Not Working when making Ajax call from React to Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894690/res-redirect-not-working-when-making-ajax-call-from-react-to-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't redirect from React with server redirects.
see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894690/res-redirect-not-working-when-making-ajax-call-from-react-to-node).

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle it on the client side. In the server response, throw an error or send a proper response as "unauthenticated". In the axios response, check the response. If the response is "unauthenticated", clear your session/local storage and redirect it to "/login".